# How to add navigation animation in @react-navigation 6.xx

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I want to add simple horizantal transition in my react-native app on both IOS/Android, I have tried this Implementation but it didnt' work:

```
<MainStack.Screen
  name="PostDetails"
  component={PostDetails}
  options={{ animation: 'slide_from_left' }}
/>
```

I am using react-navigation v 6.xx.

Thank you and have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

In the <Stack.Navigator>, which should wrap your screens, you add the parameter:

```
import {createStackNavigator, TransitionPresets} from "@react-navigation/stack";

<Stack.Navigator
screenOptions={() => ({...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS})}>
...
screens
...
</Stack.Navigator>
```

It will work for android as well.